# Equivalent parametrizations of the Radon transform

Tags: physics, rotations, parametrization, change-of-basis

Computed tomography (CT) requires integration of attenuation values along x-ray linear paths within the body at multiple different rotation angles of the x-ray tube, i.e. [Radon transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform). In [this video](https://youtu.be/MA2y_2YySq0), the linear paths, $L(\theta, t),$ are simplified as being parallel to each other and parametrized by a point $t$ along a perpendicular line to the path of the x-ray beam, as well as the angle of rotation $\theta:$

[image]

The question is the definition of $L(\theta,t)$ given as:

$$L(\theta, t) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R: x\cos\theta + y \sin\theta=t\}$$

I don't get the geometry behind this.

On the other hand, the [parametrization given in this post](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/ECE637_tomographic_reconstruction_radon_transform_S13_mhossain) makes total sense:

[image]

$$L(\theta,z)=(x(z),y(z))=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R:  x= r\cos\theta - z \sin \theta \; ; \; y = r \sin \theta + z \cos \theta\}$$

as a change of coordinate basis from $(x,y)$ to $(r,z):$

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}r\\z
\end{bmatrix}$$

How to reconcile both expressions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the case that $\theta = 0$ shouldn't $L$ describe the line $x=0$ as seen from the picture, but the mathematical expression actually describes the line $x=t$?

Comment: In particular, the set $L(\theta, t)$ as given is the tangent line to a circumference of radius $t$. Isn't that supposed to be precisely $p_\theta(t)$?

Comment: @NikiDiGiano any rotation angle has a whole set of rays sent out, not just one ray. $t$ parametrizes where along the line rotated of this angle $\theta$ this particular ray of parameter $t$ shoots out. Say for example that every ray is at some distance $\Delta_t$ from the previous.

Comment: @mathreadler I should have added that I'm fixing $\theta$ and $t$.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano yes then you get a particular whole line which the machine shoots.

Comment: If you increase $t$ a little bit, then you get a new line which another sender and receiver pair could shoot and measure and so on.

Comment: @mathreadler my point is precisely that after fixing those parameters, the line that you get is not the line that appears on the first drawing. In fact, it never crosses the origin if $t\neq 0$. So I'm confused as to what exactly $L$ is supposed to represent.

Comment: $L$ is supposed to represent a generic line which the machine could shoot if we can rotate to any precision of angle $\theta$ and precision of displacement $t$. They could draw more lines with different $t$ but picture would get messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The initial source describes a parameterization of the receptor line in Hesse normal form, and assuming the x-ray beams are parallel.

[image]

---

---

Considering the modified diagram from the OP:

[image]

$$\begin{align}
t &  \overset{?}= x\, \cos\theta + y\, \sin \theta \\[2ex]
&=x\,\cos\left (\phi +\frac\pi 2\right) + y\,\sin\left (\phi +\frac\pi 2\right)\\[2ex]
&= -x \,\sin \phi + y\, \cos \phi\\[2ex]
& = -x \frac y t + y \frac x t\\[2ex]
&=0
\end{align}$$

On the other hand, parametrizing with $ \varphi $ could work out:

$$\begin{align}
t &= x \cos(\varphi) + y \sin(\varphi)\\[2ex]
&=x \frac x t + y \frac y t\\[2ex]
&=\frac{x^2}{t}+ \frac{y^2}{t}\\[3ex]
\implies & t^2 = x^2 + y^2
\end{align}$$

This seems to be reflected [here (page 21 of 167)](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2348&context=etd):

[image]

---

And now the second parametrization in the OP matches the first parametrization only for one of the multiple parallel lines in the diagram - specifically, the line going through the origin, which would make $r=0$:

[image]

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-z\sin\theta\\
z\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, by PT, and considering the angle from the $x$ axis to the $z$ axis, $\phi = \theta+\frac \pi 2:$

$$\begin{align}z^2 &= x^2 + y^2\\[2ex]
&=x\left( -z \sin\theta \right) + y \left(z\cos \theta \right)\\[2ex]
&=x \left( -z \sin\left(\phi - \frac \pi 2 \right) \right) +
y \left( z \cos\left(\phi - \frac \pi 2 \right) \right)\\[2ex]
&=x \left( z \cos \phi\right) + y\left( z \sin \phi \right)\\[2ex]
&\implies z = x\cos\phi + y \sin \phi
\end{align}$$

And $\phi$ is exactly the equivalent of $\varphi$ in the diagram at the beginning of this answer, and $z$ is the same as $t$.